# Proper nouns and common nouns grouped together?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns

This sentence was taken from a BBC article:

> "England knocked out by late **Romania flurry**."

Is this association of words grammatical? Also, are there any more cases in which proper nouns combine with common nouns?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean this

https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/48707712

it's a page title, which is similar to a newspaper headline and is not required to be a grammatical sentence.

Country names are often combined with other nouns; in the above it indicates that England and Romania are the national teams of those countries.

*England knocked out by America* means the England and USA national teams.

*English knocked out by Americans* could mean Durham Codgers FC lost to Detroit Geriatrics FC.

Comment: "Durham Codgers FC lost to Detroit Geriatrics FC" - Never!

Comment: So, is the construction **Romania flurry** grammatical or not?

Comment: It is - in that context - correct standard English.